# Is the tf-idf of scikit-learn in this example correct? The most frequent words have high score

Tags: tf-idf, tfidfvectorizer

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

documents=["The car is driven on the road","The truck is                  
            driven on the highway","the lorry is"]
fidf_transformer=TfidfVectorizer(smooth_idf=True,use_idf=True)
tfidf=tfidf_transformer.fit_transform(documents)
print(tfidf_transformer.vocabulary_)
print(tfidf.toarray())

{'the': 7, 'car': 0, 'on': 5, 'driven': 1, 'is': 3, 'road':         6, 'lorry': 4, 'truck': 8, 'highway': 2}
[[0.45171082 0.34353772 0. 0.26678769 0.  0.34353772 0.45171082 0.53357537 0.        ]
 [0.         0.34353772 0.45171082 0.26678769 0.         0.34353772 0.         0.53357537 0.45171082]
 [0.         0.         0.         0.45329466 0.76749457 0. 0.         0.45329466 0.        ]]
```

The word "the" should have a low score in the three documents

Answer (score 0):

tfidf = term frequency (tf)* inverse doc frequency (idf)

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer 

vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(documents)
print(vectorizer.get_feature_names())
print (X.toarray())
print ("---")
t = TfidfTransformer(use_idf=True, norm=None, smooth_idf=False)
a = t.fit_transform(X)
print (a.toarray())
print ("---")
print (t.idf_)
```

Output:

[image]

idf(the) is low but the tf(the, doc1) = 2 is high which is pushing it over other words.

From the above example code:

The idf (no Norm, non smoothed idf) of is == the == 1

However tf(the, doc1) = 2 and tf(is, doc1) = 1, which bumps up the value of tfidf of tfidf(the, doc1).

similarly idf(car) = 2.09861229 but tf(car, doc1) = 1, => tfidf(car, doc1) = 2.09861229, which is very close to tfidf(the,doc1). The smoothing of idf further reduces the gap.

On a large corpus the differences become more prominent.

Try running you code by disabling smoothing and no normalisation to see the effect on small corpus.

> tfidf_transformer=TfidfVectorizer(smooth_idf=False,use_idf=True,
>   norm=None)